# Border Token Placement in Battle for Rokugan

Tags: battle-for-rokugan

The rulebook says that when placing tokens you can only place one token on a border with an ajacent province. Is this limit of one token per player or one token total?

For example, I place a token on a border attacking an opponents province, can they also place a token on the same border attacking my province? Or does the fact I've already placed a token prevent this?

Comment: Aww I miss the good ol' L5R... regarding your question I guess that you can have as much tokens as you can as long as each fits the "on a border with an adjacent province" condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/95/ef/95ef7efa-c0e1-4ae9-bd33-5439d236cefb/l5b01_rulebook_webcompressed.pdf) say:

> Only one combat token can be placed on each border.

No qualification or exception is made to this statement, so I see no reason to not interpret it as only one total. Furthermore, none of the battle examples show more than one token on each border.

Answer (score 0):

My group interprets battle token placement as follows: the owner of a province can only place 1 combat token on a border when attacking, but adjacent provinces can attack you back. If you interpret the rule as @user30903 suggests, attacking becomes a defensive move, as you can limit other people from attacking you by attacking them. This seems like an incorrect interpretation of the rules, since, if you want to make a defensive move, then defend. If you want to attack, then attack, but one single token (regardless of its value) shouldn't be used to attack and prevent an attack at the same time.

I have found that BFR is pretty clear about its rules, if it's not expressly forbidden, you can't make up a rule to prevent it.

Comment: The rules state "Only one combat token can be placed on each border. Combat tokens are always placed facedown. (The exception to both of
these rules is the blessing token, which is explained later.)" which offers no alternative rules for placing while defending. Therefore unless playing with houserules I believe the accepted answer to be correct